# mysql_real_escape_string and search data in mySql DB

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have problem with php function : mysql_real_escape_string

My test string:

```
    @,&!#$%^*()_+' "\/
```

I add this data to mySql database, like that (in short):

```
    $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table(company) VALUES('".$str. "')";
```

In DB is stored as:

```
    @,&!#$%^*()_+\' \"\\/
```

But problem is with find this data by SELECT statement.

I want find, company where name is like

```
    ' "
```

My SELECT's:

```
    SELECT company FROM table WHERE company LIKE '%\' "%';
    SELECT company FROM table WHERE company LIKE '%\\' \\"%';
```

;
not working.

This works:

```
    SELECT `company` FROM `table` WHERE `company` LIKE '%\\\' \\\\"%';

    and

    SELECT `company` FROM `table` WHERE `company` LIKE  '%\\\\\\\' \\\\\\\"%'
```

But I dont know why this work :(.

My questions are:

- why must add so many slashes ?
- how I can make correct query in PHP:

```
    $query = '\' "';
    '%'.mysql_real_escape_string($query).'%' 
    result is : '%\' \"%'

    '%'.mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_real_escape_string($query)).'%'
    result is : '%\\\' \\\"%'

    '%'.mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_real_escape_string($query))).'%' 
    result is : '%\\\\\\\' \\\\\\\"%'
```

Only last one works good.

Comment: simply go through the addslashes() manual  http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Note: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/296974

Comment: If you use `like` you have to escape the string twice.  If you use equals, you only need to do it once.  I'm not sure why exactly but I just know it needs to be done like that.... and I'm also not sure why you need to do this a third time, though...?  You should really use the mysqli_ or PDO functions b/c they are going to remove mysql_ from PHP entirely soon.  (this might also be an issue with `get_magic_quotes_gpc`)

Comment: I can not change that (mysql_*). I changed just a piece of software, I have no influence on the methods used to communicate with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using old method since it won't support from PHP team!

Lets try using PDO! it would do it for you with `bindvalue`.

It's secure much more than the old method

```
$db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
'user', 'pass');
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Cannot Connect to the DB!';
}

$sql = 'SELECT name, description
FROM recipes
WHERE chef = :chef';
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':chef', 'Lorna');
$stmt->execute();
```

that's it and there is no need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Lets have a try

Comment: Because it's a part of an old project that is not yet using PDO

Comment: It's important that whenever the server is updated , your project wont work correctly. by the way , I recommend you to use `str_replace('"\\','"\')` after `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Thans Mr.Farahmand. Problem was in double escaping of my string (in other place in program). But You simple tip with str_replace() helps me very much. Because, searching of char \ strill not worked. In my case I used : <pre>$query = str_replace('\\','\\\\', $query);</pre> +1 for You :)